# arithmetic operations with lenght function

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have this Dataframe

```
+----+----+------+------+------+----+
|key1|key2|  col1|  col2|  col3|col4|
+----+----+------+------+------+----+
|   5|   d|value7|value8|value9|  20|
+----+----+------+------+------+----+
```

And I am trying to do something like this

```
df2.withColumn("new",repeat(lit("0"), 10-length(col("col3")) )).show()
```

But I get this error message **TypeError: Column is not iterable**

I would like to know if there is any way to do a subtraction or maybe an addition using **"length("col3")"**

Comment: a pyspark sql function requiring an integer input will not accept a column expression, as in the case of `repeat()`. this can, however, be bypassed by using their SQL equivalents (using `expr()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#repeat) as SQL function instead of using the [Python function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.repeat.html) works:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('new', F.expr('repeat("0", 10-length(col3))')).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+
|  col3|  new|
+------+-----+
| hello|00000|
|value9| 0000|
+------+-----+
```